# Stochastic Dominance of Polynomial CDFs on [0, 1]

Tags: polynomials, monotone-functions

Let $\mathcal{P}_n$ be the set of all polynomials of degree $n$ or smaller, and consider the following subset:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{M}_n = \left\{
    F \in \mathcal{P}_n: F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, F(x) \nearrow x \in [0, 1]
\right\}.
\end{equation}
Here, $F(x) \nearrow x \in [0, 1]$ means that $F$ is monotonically increasing on $[0, 1]$. For all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$, I would like to show
\begin{equation}
    x^n \le F(x) \le 1 - (1 - x)^n,
    \quad \forall F \in \mathcal{M}_n,
          \forall x \in [0, 1].
\end{equation}
In fact, it would suffice to prove just one inequality, as the other would follow from symmetry. For context, I use $F$ to denote a member of $\mathcal{M}_n$ because it is a function that could serve as a CDF for a random variable with unit interval support. The result I am trying to prove pertains to first-order stochastic dominance. It is clear to me that for $F \in \mathcal{M}_n$ represented as $F(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$, the following conditions must hold:
\begin{align*}
    & a_0 = 0 && \text{for}~F(0) = 0, \\
    & \textstyle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = 1 && \text{for}~F(1) = 1, \\
    & \textstyle F'(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\,k\,x^{k-1} \ge 0, \quad x \in [0, 1] && \text{for monotonicity}. \\
\end{align*}

However, it is unclear to me if this is the best characterization to prove (or disprove) the desired result. I tried starting with $\mathcal{M}_1 = \{x\}$ and then applying induction, but I have so far come up empty. Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: Possible solution: I think you should be able to show that for any $f \in \mathcal{M}_n$, there exists a $g \in \mathcal{M}_{n-1}$ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = x(\alpha g(x) + 1 - \alpha)$? The argument follows by induction after that. I think the claim is true though I haven't worked out all the details.

Comment: @sudeep5221 That sort of direction is what makes sense to me. The main issue is that while every $f(x) = x(\alpha g(x) + 1 - \alpha)$ is certainly a member of $\mathcal{M}_n$, not every member of $\mathcal{M}_n$ cannot be represented that way. For example, $f(x) = -x^2 + 2x \in \mathcal{M}_2$ cannot be represented as $x (\alpha g(x) + (1 - \alpha))$ for $\alpha \in [0, 1], g \in \mathcal{M}_1 = \{x\}$.

Comment: That's a good point. How about either $f(x) = x(\alpha g(x) + (1 - \alpha))$ or $f(x) = x(1 - \alpha g(1-x))$? I think one takes care of convex functions and the other of concave functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is true for $\mathcal{M}_1 = \{x\}$ and $\mathcal{M}_2 = \{\alpha x + (1 - \alpha) : \alpha \in [0, 1]\}$. However, there are polynomials in $\mathcal{M}_3$ that do not satisfy the desired inequalities.

For example, $\exists x \in [0, 1]$ such that $3.97 x - 6.24 x^2 + 3.27 x^3 > 1 - (1 - x)^3$. Likewise, $\exists x \in [0, 1]$ such that $0.44 x - 1.74 x^2 + 2.30 x^3 < x^3$.

[image: counterexample]